# Ошибка функции ⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀⠀​⠀⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀​⠀⠀​⠀

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел перенисти фильтрацию `fuzzywuzzy`  в отдельную функцию `FuzzTest` но выдает 3 ошибки.
код

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import pyttsx3
import webbrowser
import datetime
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import string

# Функция, позволяющая проговаривать слова
# Принимает параметр "Слова" и прогроваривает их


# Оброшение
alias = ['арка', 'ара', 'арара', 'аришенька', 'арочка'] # оброшение (для удаления)
tbr = ['скажи', 'расскажи', 'сказать'] # Просьба сказать (для удаления)
cname = ['зовут', 'название', 'прозвище',]# имя
csearch = ['найди', 'загугли', 'поиск', 'подскажи', 'найдика', 'найди в интернете'] # поиск
# Время
ctime = ['время', 'час'] # время
ctimer = ['таймер', 'засеки', 'засеки время']#таймер
csleep = ['засни', 'усни', 'засыпай', 'отключись'] # отключение на время
# Приложения
calc = ['сколько будеть', 'сколько', 'посчитай', 'сложи', 'умнож', 'раздели', 'вычти'] # калькулятор




def talk(words):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()

talk("Здравствуйте, чем я могу помочь вам?")

def command(): 
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Говорите")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try: 
        theTask = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print("Вы сказали: " + theTask)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        talk("Я вас не поняла")
        theTask = command()

    return theTask







# .............. ответ .............
def replay():
    if ctimeT == True:
        talk("Сейчас " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M'))
        print("Сейчас " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    elif csearchT == True:
        for x in csearch:
            adress = theTask.replace(x,'').strip()
            break
        url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + adress
    elif cnameT == True:
        talk("Меня зовут Арка")

    elif 'стоп' in theTask:
        talk("До Свидания!")
        sys.exit()





#....................... удаление ненужных слов .....................




def fuzzTest(theTask):
    #....................... Проверка на слова .....................
    global replay
    for x in alias:
        fuzAlias = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, theTask)
        if fuzAlias >= 50:
            aliasT = True
        else:
            aliasT = False


    for x in tbr:
        fuzTbr = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, theTask)
        if fuzTbr >= 50:
            tbrT = True
            break
        else:
            tbrT = False


    for x in ctime:
        fuzCtime = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, theTask)
        if fuzCtime >= 50:
            ctimeT = True
            break
        else:
            ctimeT = False


    for x in cname:
        fuzCname = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, theTask)
        if fuzCname >= 50:
            cnameT = True
            break
        else:
             cnameT = False


    for x in csearch:
        fuzCsearch = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, theTask)
        if fuzCsearch >= 50:
            csearchT = True
            break
        else:
             csearchT = False
    replay()

while True:
    fuzzTest(command())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Голосовой помошник\ARCA.py", line 134, in <module>
    makeSomething(command())
  File "C:\Голосовой помошник\ARCA.py", line 127, in makeSomething
    replay()
  File "C:\Голосовой помошник\ARCA.py", line 62, in replay
    if ctimeT == True:
NameError: name 'ctimeT' is not defined
```

Comment: Очевидно, у вас нет переменной ctimeT

Comment: Когда вы переносили, то не все перенесли, у вас эта переменная должна объявляться ранее, до того как вы делаете проверку if ctimeT == True:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `replay` вы проверяете переменные, которые вы выставляете в функции `fuzzTest`, однако, поскольку эти переменные не объявлены как глобальные (в обоих функциях), они являются локальными для обоих этих функций и они не видны из другой функции.

Проще всего объявить все нужные переменные как `global` вначале обоих функций, хотя это и не самое хорошее решение. Хорошее решение - сделать класс, который будет содержать эти функции/методы и эти переменные/поля. Тогда они будут доступны внутри класса всем вашим функциям.

Answer (score 0):

У вас просто нет переменной `ctimeT` так как написано: `NameError: name 'ctimeT' is not defined` - то есть примерно `ОшибкаИмени: не объявлена переменная 'ctimeT'`.
Переменная ctimeT у вас просто не объявлена. Наверно когда вы переносили код в функцию, забыли её перенести!

P.S. Надо научиться читать сообщение об ошибке. И там только одна ошибка.